# Graph data structure implementation in C

Tags: c, graph

I have learned the basics of graph data structures.  Now I want to implement all the structure/algorithms/operations that can be performed on graphs.

Please share some useful links wherein I can get started doing graph implementations in C.

Answer (score 3):

[adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) and [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) are the two most classic alternatives for implementing graphs.  I'm not sure if there are many examples of each online in C, but [here](http://www.indiastudychannel.com/resources/12983-C-Program-for-creation-adjacency-matrix.aspx) is one for the adjacency matrix representation.

Comment: Thanks Alex.... Looks pretty good example... I will work it out..... but there is one article on adjacency list with incomplete implementation  http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/graph/linked/........ But i am finding it difficult to get the start.... Can you help it out..... I have understood the structures,, but now if we want to insert a vertex or edge.. etc....

Comment: @AGeek, in adj matrix: insert edge (between existing vertices I and J) → just set the `matrix[I][J]=1`; insert new vertex N+1 → allocate new N+1 by N+1 matrix and copy the old one over padding with the new row and col of 0s. adj list: in adj matrix: insert edge (between existing vertices I and J) → append J to the adj list of I; insert new vertex → append it to the list of existing vertices.

Answer (score 1):

The book,[The Algorithm Design Manual](http://sist.sysu.edu.cn/~isslxm/DSA/textbook/Skiena.-.TheAlgorithmDesignManual.pdf)[PDF] has C code implementing a graph.

For a more thorough textbook on graphs and related algorithms (DFS, Bellman-Ford etc) [Introduction to Algorithms](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms) (excellent) has pseudocode implementations that you could implement.

The standard adjacency list or matrix representations mentioned by Alex are described in both.